# Replace only the regular expression match at the very end of a string

Tags: r, regex

Say here I want to only get rid of the number at the very end for each of the string in my loop. The code is as the following.

```
test.data1 <- c('kfc-north-memphis-11', 'kfc-123-olive-branch-123')

output <- rep(NA, 2)

for (i in 1:length(test.data1)){
  string <- test.data1[i]
  pattern.1 <- '-[0-9]*$'
  mat.1 <- regexpr(pattern.1, string)
  sub.string <- regmatches(string, mat.1)
  out.string <- sub(sub.string, '', string)
  }
  output[i] <- out.string
}
```

But the output I got is not what I want for the second string. I got the following output.

```
# kfc-north-memphis', 'kfc-olive-branch-123
```

It seems that for the second string, it removes the first match '-123' instead of the one at the ending of the string. Is there any way I can fix it?

BTW, I know that I can use `sub("123$', '', string)` to force only remove the match at the very end. But here it seems I cannot use the way in a loop with a defined variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your process uses a pattern to detect a substring match, and then uses that match as a pattern in `sub` to do a replacement. This is convoluted - better to use a pattern to do a replacement directly. In your second case, the substring match is repeated, and that extracted pattern doesn't "remember" it needs to be at the end of the string.

We can directly make the replacement using your pattern in a single line. `sub` is vectorized, so there is no need for a `for` loop:

```
output = sub('-[0-9]*$', '', test.data1)
output
# [1] "kfc-north-memphis"    "kfc-123-olive-branch"
```

Comment: Thanks, really make a lot of sense for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
sub('-\\d+$', '', test.data1)
#[1] "kfc-north-memphis"    "kfc-123-olive-branch"
```

Or an alternative is to capture what you want to keep.

```
sub('(.*)-\\d+$', '\\1', test.data1)
```